# How to open a wxWidgets dialog?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

In wxWidgets, how do I open a dialog (like an options one) in code?

I have Googled and Binged it and nothing comes up! Any help appreciated!

Comment: How to open a dialog is explained in wxDialog documentation, how much easier to find can it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the code example on this page:
http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxdialog.html#wxdialog

> ```
> void AskUser()
> {
>     MyAskDialog dlg(...);
>     if ( dlg.ShowModal() == wxID_OK )
>         ...
>
>     // no need to call Destroy() here
> }
> ```